# partial result with curl

Tags: php, curl, partial

I'm trying to curl a site, but it cuts off after 1481 characters. Any idea why that could be?

```
$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_URL,'http://brickset.com/parts/design-30363/colour-Br-Red');
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,2);
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$buffer = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);

if (empty($buffer)){
    print "Nothing returned from url.<p>";
}
else{
    echo $buffer;
}
?>
```

curl settings: http://www.one-docs.com/php5

Comment: Without the URL it would be hard to help you out!

Comment: ahh, ok: http://brickset.com/parts/design-30363/colour-Br-Red

Comment: 1481 characters? That sounds suspiciously like a typical MTU size.

Comment: It is around the 1500 mark which makes me suspect it, but I'm not sure what I can do to counter it using curl.

Comment: Would it be any trouble to post the actual response you get? You might have to add a user agent if you are getting blocked.

Comment: is anyone else here able to replicate the problem?

Comment: not being blocked as far as I can tell. If You go to the URL then I get Everything up until row 80 where it Cuts of at:

<li><a href="/login" c

that's c as in class, so nothing strange or out of the ordinary

Comment: You probably overdid the calls to their system getting your IP blocked. I am able to retrieve the entire page using the above code.

Comment: thanks, Aziz - I have no idea what caused it, but I restarted the webserver - no Changes made or anything and now it works just fine